# Mobile nav pushing hero section down

Tags: javascript, html, css

When the mobile nav menu active, it pushes down the hero section. Rather than staying put while the mobile nav is active. I hope this make sense.

Here i have the actual code to my issue i'm currently facing.

```js
const navOpen = () => {
  const menuToggle = document.querySelector('.menu-toggle');
  const nav = document.querySelector('nav');

  menuToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
    nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');
    menuToggle.classList.toggle('toggle');
  });
}

navOpen();
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background: #161414;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 60px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

nav {
  float: right;
  margin: 5px 20px;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  color: #ffffff;
  opacity: .7;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}

nav ul li a.active,
nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  transition: .4s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 1;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.menu-toggle {
  display: none;
}

.menu-toggle span {
  width: 40px;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #ffffff;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.toggle span {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px, 5px);
}

.menu-toggle span:nth-child(2) {
  margin: 17px 0;
}

.toggle span:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
}

.menu-toggle span:last-child {
  margin: 27px 0;
}

.toggle span:last-child {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-7px, -9px);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .menu-toggle {
    display: block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    float: right;
    margin: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  nav {
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9999;
  }
  nav ul {
    display: block;
  }
  nav ul li {
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: .4s ease-in-out;
  }
  nav ul li:hover {
    background: #000;
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  nav ul li a {
    padding: 40px 0;
  }
}

.nav-active {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.hero {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #ffffff;
}

.main-hero {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1050px;
  height: 70vh;
  background: salmon;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/app.css" type="text/css">
  <title>portfolio three</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <a href="#" class="logo">PORTFOLIO</a>
      <div class="menu-toggle">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </div>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#" class="active">HOME</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">WORK</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </header>
  <section class="hero">
    <div class="main-hero"></div>
  </section>







  <script src="/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kt3ce5L4/1/)

I expect the hero section to stay when the mobile nav drop.

I think what's inside here is the problem look at the link i provided

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {}
```

Comment: you should set the `position` of the `header` to either `absolute` or `fixed` and give the appropriate `padding` to the `body` in the mobile setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing your headers `position` from `relative` to `absolute` does the trick.

> to learn more about the position property take a look at [its documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

You also have to add a `padding` equal to your navs height to your section.

> thats because your absolute positioned header will overlay your section. Using `padding` you will be able to make sure, that your whole section will be visible.

```
header {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background: #161414;
}

section {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
```

Take a look at the example below:

```js
const navOpen = () => {
  const menuToggle = document.querySelector('.menu-toggle');
  const nav = document.querySelector('nav');

  menuToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
    nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');
    menuToggle.classList.toggle('toggle');
  });
}

navOpen();
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background: #161414;
}

section {
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 60px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

nav {
  float: right;
  margin: 5px 20px;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  color: #ffffff;
  opacity: .7;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}

nav ul li a.active,
nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  transition: .4s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 1;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.menu-toggle {
  display: none;
}

.menu-toggle span {
  width: 40px;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #ffffff;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.toggle span {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px, 5px);
}

.menu-toggle span:nth-child(2) {
  margin: 17px 0;
}

.toggle span:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
}

.menu-toggle span:last-child {
  margin: 27px 0;
}

.toggle span:last-child {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-7px, -9px);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .menu-toggle {
    display: block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    float: right;
    margin: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  nav {
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9999;
  }
  nav ul {
    display: block;
  }
  nav ul li {
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: .4s ease-in-out;
  }
  nav ul li:hover {
    background: #000;
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  nav ul li a {
    padding: 40px 0;
  }
}

.nav-active {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.hero {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #ffffff;
}

.main-hero {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1050px;
  height: 70vh;
  background: salmon;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/app.css" type="text/css">
  <title>portfolio three</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <a href="#" class="logo">PORTFOLIO</a>
      <div class="menu-toggle">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </div>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#" class="active">HOME</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">WORK</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </header>
  <section class="hero">
    <div class="main-hero"></div>
  </section>







  <script src="/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Appreciate the help J. I'm aware about the positioning "absolute" and "relative", but i can't wrap my head around where to put it.